# Is there a function that can get me the url of the directory of the file I'm working on? (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to include some JS to my theme.
I created a folder called "js" in my twentyfifteen-child theme folder.

When I want to call the file I write the whole text:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen-child/js/scroll.js'></script>
```

Is there a function that does that in a more simple way instead of typing the whole directory myself?
It's useful when moving the website to a new server ect'. 
What is your solution for this situation ?

Comment: You can use [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) to get the directory of the current theme.

Comment: I already tried it it echos: http://54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen 
 - and my folder is terntyfifteen-child 
   @AndreiP.

Comment: try get_stylesheet_uri() then, it should work for child themes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scroll.js'></script>
```

`get_template_directory_uri()` function return directory path of current active theme.

**EDIT:**
Try the follwoing function to get child theme directory.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/scroll.js'></script>
```

Comment: I already tried it it echos: 54.149.xx.xx/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen - and my folder is terntyfifteen-child

Answer (score 1):

First of all Hatul, you have better chances of  getting an answer by asking this question on the WordPress Development site of stack exchange.

```
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/
```

Second you should use the following code in your plugin file or functions.php file.

```
wp_enqueue_script('your_js_handle', plugins_url('your_js_folder/your_js_file.js',__FILE__) ,array('any_dependency_the_js_file_might_require',false);
```

For `your_js_handle` you can put any name but do not include spaces.
your_js_handle is the id of the file that will be available in the HTML DOM.

`Plugins_url` is the function you should use if you are working with a plugin.Else
you should use `get_template_directory_uri('your_js_folder/your_js_file.js')`.

`__FILE__`is written with 2 underscores  before and after the word so that is not an error and what `__FILE__` will do is that it will retrieve the relative path of the file you are working with.

`array('any_dependency_the_js_file_might_require',false)` should be used if the javascript file requires any library in order to work. like if your plugin require the jQuery library then you have to use it by stating array('jquery').
if your plugin requires the jQuery library make sure you are  enqueuing it before using it. Wordpress normally comes with a preinstalled jQuery library which is the latest version. To use it just state

```
 wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
```

Finally `false` means either you render the file in the footer or the header of your site. In which case you should make sure you are using `wp_head()` or `wp_footer()` as required. If you set it to true, the script is placed before the  end tag.

Hope that helps you to  code with best practice.

Yours.

MMK